# How to get unique values from table() function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, select, frequency

I have a data frame which 31 columns. In column of Year (named "Anos"), I have rows which years are repeated and when I use table(df$Anos), I get frequency of years. **I need only years with 12 observations (12 months)**.

Example:

`freq_years <- table(df$Anos)
freq_years
Result:
2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2017 2018 2019 2020 
  10   12   12    3   11    6    8   12   12   12    5`

How to get automatically in a new variable only years with freq = 12? (maybe like 2010,2011,2018,2019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` version. Depending on your use with the other 30 columns in your data frame, keeping the data as `df2` might be useful.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("magrittr")
library("magrittr")
library("dplyr")
#create example dataset
df <- data.frame("Anos" = c(rep(2009,10),
                            rep(2010,12),
                            rep(2011,12),
                            rep(2012,3),
                            rep(2013,11),
                            rep(2014,6),
                            rep(2015,8),
                            rep(2016,12),
                            rep(2017,12)))

head(df)

# count number of years by row and filter to those with only 12 
df2 <- df %>% group_by(Anos) %>% count() %>% filter(n == 12)

head(df2)

# create variable with list of years that have exactly 12 rows
variable <- df2$Anos

variable
```

Comment: It is exactly what I needed, works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical vector and subset the `names` of the `table` output

```
names(freq_years)[freq_years == 12]
```